# How to remove pipe sealed with silicone

Tags: plumbing, adhesive, pvc, plumbing-fixture, silicone

My kitchen sink is emptying very slowly. The pipes under the sink are clear. So the blockage must be somewhere in the pipe from the wall on. Unfortunately the curved pieces of pipe are in the way and I need to remove them.

[image]

Guessing from what I removed with a knife at the point pointed by the three arrows, it is glued together with silicone but when I attempted to remove it, it didn't budge :(

I don't want to force it and break something. Any suggestions on how to get it unstuck?

EDIT: Fixed picture as it was not clear. Also, should clarify, I am trying to separate the grey piece from the one coming out of the wall.

Answer (score 2):

You don't remove it.  The silicone is probably just to secure the pipe to the wall - so it doesn't wiggle or so that air doesn't get in.

If you need access to the pipe I would cut the white pipe.  This would allow you to fully snake anything below.  Chances are pretty high that all of these pipes are glued very well together.  They are not meant to wiggle apart.  If you do not want to cut them then you can try putting in a snake from a point further up or you can see if you have access from below in your main stack.

Comment: Sorry, I realised the picture was misleading so I've updated it. I am not trying to remove pipe going into the wall, its the the piece before.

Comment: My answer is the same.  I doubt that piece was made to be removed.  If it was it was because the person that did it is suspect - which maybe you got lucky, but doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad job to me - might well be glued with silicone by someone who really should not have been doing plumbing. If so, grab onto the silicone blobs with pliers and pull - it will come right off, usually. Having removed as much as possible that way, pull/twist the pipe. Once you clear the blockage, consider reassembling correctly, which won't be with silicone...

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my question when you posted your answer. Does it help?